# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk - Any file managers?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Are there any file manager UIs I can use with Elastic Beanstalk (upload,view,etc)? Does the AWS Management Console include one? I'm doing PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The management console cannot be used to deploy PHP apps...

here is an extract of the [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/en/elasticbeanstalk/#functionality):

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk Functionality For PHP Developers
>
> To deploy PHP applications using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, you simply:
>
> Create your application as you normally would using any editor or IDE.
>   Create an Elastic Beanstalk PHP environment using the AWS Management
>   Console, the command line interface, or the web service APIs. Behind
>   the scenes, Elastic Beanstalk handles the provisioning of a load
>   balancer and Amazon EC2 resources. Install and configure Git for
>   deployments. Commit and push your changes using Git. Elastic Beanstalk
>   deploys your files to one or more Amazon EC2 instances running the
>   Apache HTTP Server. Within a few minutes you will be able to access
>   your application at a customized URL (e.g.
>   http://myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/).

Comment: You're correct. It appears the only thing you can do with the AWS Management console is upload your _entire website_ in a zip file, where using Git makes it much easier to upload individual file changes. There's even some Git UIs on the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Elastic Beanstalk can be managed through the AWS Management Console<sup>[1](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/01/aws-beanstalk-console.html)</sup> .

Answer (score 1):

I very often SSH into my Beanstalk instances and use [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) (Windows) with SFTP plugin to check things etc. Highly recommendable.